# NextJS rewrites error while proxying a request to the backend

Tags: next.js, proxy, url-rewriting, nextjs-rewrites

I'm trying to proxy a request to a backend with Next rewrites.

next.config.js:

```
async rewrites() {
  return [
    {
      source: "/api/:path*",
      destination: "http://somedomain.loc/api/:path*",
    },  
  ]
},
```

/etc/host:

```
127.0.0.1  somedomain.loc
```

and in the end i get this error:

```
Failed to proxy http://somedomain.loc/api/offers Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:80
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1159:16) {
  errno: -111,
  code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
  syscall: 'connect',
  address: '127.0.0.1',
  port: 80
}
error - Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:80
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1159:16) {
  errno: -111,
  code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
  syscall: 'connect',
  address: '127.0.0.1',
  port: 80
}
```

While if you make a request via postman or directly from the browser, everything works fine.

Please help me understand what is the problem here.

tried:
Proxy request to backend
expected:
The request is proxied to the backend
as a result:
Proxy error

Comment: I'm facing the same issue. Were you able to find a solution to this?

Comment: Alright, using the IP address `127.0.0.1` instead of the domain name `localhost` worked for me. The issue might be with the domain name resolution with NextJS.

Comment: I am using the IP address and not localhost... If I type the URL directly into the browser it works, but not when I have the request rewritten by Next.js